# phpmailer html email problem

Tags: html, email, phpmailer

i tried to send html email but i guess i am doing sth wrong

here is my code for body part

```
$body .= "<table style=width: 800px; height: 600px;background-image: url('http://www.myserver.net/image/temp1.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat><tr><td><table style=width: 100%>";
    $body .= "<tr><td align=center  style=width: 345px><img height=350 style=width: 350px /></td><td align=center><table style=width: 100%; height: 364px><tr>";
    $body .= "<td style=height: 126px><img height=107 width=307 /></td></tr><tr><td><table style=width: 100%; height: 215px><tr><td  style=width: 64px></td>";
    $body .= "<td align=left  style=width: 105px>Artist Name</td><td style=width: 22px>:</td><td>" . $aname ."</td></tr><tr><td style=width: 64px></td>";
    $body .= "<td align=left  style=width: 105px>Title</td><td style=width: 22px>:</td><td>" . $rname ."</td></tr><tr><td style=width: 64px></td>";
    $body .= "<td align=left  style=width: 105px>Release Date</td><td style=width: 22px>:</td><td>" . $rdate ."</td></tr><tr><td style=width: 64px></td>";
    $body .= "<td align=left  style=width: 105px>Tracks</td><td style=width: 22px>:</td><td><table style=width: 100%><tr><td></td></tr></table></td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style=width: 64px></td><td style=width: 105px></td><td style=width: 22px></td><td></td></tr><tr><td style=width: 64px></td>";
    $body .= "<td style=width: 105px></td><td style=width: 22px></td><td></td></tr><tr><td style=width: 64px></td>";
    $body .= "<td style=width: 105px></td><td style=width: 22px></td><td></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td  align=center>If you want to unsubscribe from this promo list, please <a href=http://www.myserver.net/promo/unsubs.php?lid=". $id  .">click here</a></td></tr></table>";
```

but it resulted like that in gmail

[alt text http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/8618/screenhunter01oct232033.jpg](http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/8618/screenhunter01oct232033.jpg)

what is wrong ??

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail strips out background images. Unfortunately, with HTML e-mail, you're really limited in what you can do with CSS.

See this article for more info:
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/designers-guide-html-email

Answer (score 0):

First off, add some quotes around your styles:

```
$body .= "<table style=\"width: 800px; height: 600px;background-image: url('http://www.myserver.net/image/temp1.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat\">

<tr><td><table style=\"width: 100%\">";
```